# Fake program runtime environment

Tags: mount, directory, chroot

Is it possible to run a program in a fake environment?

I have a tool that requires a certain folder to be in `/mnt/cdrom`. I have the all the files from that cdrom stored in another folder, say /home/me/stuff. How can I pretend (just for one run of that program) that `/home/me/stuff` is actually `/mnt/cdrom`? I do not have root access so mount will not work.

Comment: I take it this tool will not accept a symlink? e.g. `ln -s /mnt/cdrom /home/me/stuff` (assuming /home/me/stuff does not already exist)

Comment: @geirha That command will create a symlink called `/home/me/stuff` to `/mnt/cdrom`. This will succeed if `/mnt/cdrom` exists (in Ubuntu by default it does not), but that will not make it possible to alter the contents of `/mnt/cdrom` (which by default even if it did exist, you'd have to be `root` to accomplish). In contrast, if you meant `ln -s /home/me/stuff /mnt/cdrom`, that would attempt to create `/mnt/cdrom` as a symbolic link to `/home/me/stuff`, but this will fail if you are not `root` because only `root` can modify the contents of `/mnt` by default.

Comment: @EliahKagan I meant what I said. henkenen did not specify whether write access was needed, only that the content of /mnt/cdrom should be available as /home/me/stuff.

Comment: @henkenen Can you tell us more about the program, its name, what it does, why it needs to access `/mnt/cdrom`, what language it's written in (if you know)? You can edit your question to provide this info. If you are going to be able to fool the program into thinking `/home/me/stuff` is really `/mnt/cdrom`, the way you do it will probably depend on some of these details. For example, if the program is a script (a text file containing code in an interpreted language, that can run as an executable), you could just edit it to use `/home/me/stuff` instead of `/mnt/cdrom`.

Comment: @geirha No, you have misunderstood the question. The files are *not* in `/mnt/cdrom`. The files are in `/home/me/stuff`. The OP needs to get the program to access them in `/home/me/stuff` even though the program is only designed to access them in `/mnt/cdrom`.

Comment: @EliahKagan Oh, you're right. I just reread the question. Sorry.

Comment: Are you comfortable running it in a chroot?

Comment: What is the program written in?

Answer (score 1):

you could run it in a chroot environment..but odds are chroot would 1 require a fair amount of work, and 2. more importantly would require root access.  (in which case sudo ln -s /mnt/cdrom /home/me/stuff would be much easier. ).

I would suggest just having a VM you can boot/play.  VMware Player can play a VM you setup somewhere else...and you probably can run VMware player or Virtualbox from your $HOME w/o installing it.  With some work.